# Validação falha

Tags: javascript

Estou escrevendo uma function para validar somente números em um caso e somente letras em outro, no entanto, quando eu só tinha uma function para validarNumeros, a function dava certo, quando eu tenho as duas ao mesmo tempo, ambas dão errado.

```
function somenteNumeros(num) {
        var er = /[^0-9]/;
        er.lastIndex = 0;
        var campo = num;
        if (er.test(campo.value)) {
            campo.value = "";
        }
    }
    function somenteLetras(letra) {
        var er = /[^a-zA-Z]/s;
        er.lastIndex = 0;
        var campo = letra;
        if(er.test(campo.value)){
            campo.value = "";
        }
    }

<input type="text" size="35" name="nomeOutro" onkeyup="somenteLetras(this)" minlength="3" maxlength="150"/>

<input type="text" size="1" name="idade" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this)" maxlength="3"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em JavaScript não existe a flag `s` em RegExp. Tira e já vai funcionar como queres:

```
var er = /[^a-zA-Z\s]/;
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xs6hj5LL/

Podias simplificar a lógica e ter só uma função... assim:

```js
function valida(el, regex) {
    if (regex.test(el.value)) {
        el.value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="35" name="nomeOutro" onkeyup="valida(this, /[^a-zA-Z\s]/)" minlength="3" maxlength="150" />
<input type="text" size="1" name="idade" onkeyup="valida(this, /[^0-9]/)" maxlength="3" />
```

Comment: Como posso deixar permitido espaço então ?

Comment: @CaioVieira juntei essa possibilidade na resposta.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado